# How do I find the percentage error in a Monte Carlo algorithm?

Tags: python, math, percentage, montecarlo

I have written a Monte Carlo program to integrate a function f(x).

I have now been asked to calculate the percentage error.

Having done a quick literature search, I found that this can be given with the equation %error = (sqrt(var[f(x)]/n))*100, where n is the number of random points I used to derive my answer.

However, when I run my integration code, my percentage error is greater than that given by this formula.

Do I have the correct formula?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks x

Comment: "Is there anything I'm doing wrong?" How could we possibly know? Please give a [mcve]. It is very hard to debug code which you can't see. Also -- are you trying to *estimate* the error, or calculate the actual error (which would require knowledge of the true value that you are trying to estimate)?

Comment: Hi @John Coleman, I don't think it is a problem with my code directly, but with the maths I'm using to work out the error. I can't post my entire code because it is part of my coursework, sorry.

Comment: The formula that you give seems to be for a *standard error* -- which is used to estimate errors. It can't possibly give you the exact error for a particular function.

Comment: But doesn't the var[f(x)] refer to a specific function? i.e. I have found the var of the function I am integrating within the limits I am integrating through.

Comment: Percentage error is something like `(true_value - estimated_value)/true_value * 100`, which requires knowledge of the true value, which in this case is an integral. What you have given seems to be an *estimator* for the error.

Comment: But the estimator for the error is supposed to be an upper bound on the error.  Having a substantially larger percentage error than the estimator points to something being wrong.  That being said, I'm not sure what you mean by `var[f]`, and a Monte Carlo method could overestimate.  But it comes back to the original complaint that we need a MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick example - estimate integral of linear function on the interval [0...1] using Monte-Carlo. To estimate error you have to collect second momentum (values squared), then compute variance, standard deviation, and (assuming CLT), error of the simulation in the original units as well as in %

Code, Python 3.7, Anaconda, Win10 64x

```
import numpy as np

def f(x): # linear function to integrate
    return x

np.random.seed(312345)

N = 100000

x  = np.random.random(N)
q  = f(x)  # first momentum
q2 = q*q   # second momentum

mean = np.sum(q) / float(N) # compute mean explicitly, not using np.mean
var  = np.sum(q2) / float(N) - mean * mean # variance as E[X^2] - E[X]^2
sd   = np.sqrt(var) # std.deviation

print(mean) # should be 1/2
print(var)  # should be 1/12
print(sd)   # should be 0.5/sqrt(3)
print("-----------------------------------------------------")

sigma = sd / np.sqrt(float(N)) # assuming CLT, error estimation in original units

print("result = {0} with error +- {1}".format(mean, sigma))

err_pct = sigma / mean * 100.0 # error estimate in percents

print("result = {0} with error +- {1}%".format(mean, err_pct))
```

Be aware, that we computed one sigma error and (even not talking about it being random value itself) true result is within printed mean+-error only for 68% of the runs. You could print mean+-2*error, and it would mean true result is inside that region for 95% cases, mean+-3*error true result is inside that region for 99.7% of the runs and so on and so forth.

UPDATE

For sampling variance estimate, there is known problem called [Bias in the estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator). Basically, we underestimate a bit sampling variance, proper correction (Bessel's correction) shall be applied

```
var  = np.sum(q2) / float(N) - mean * mean # variance as E[X^2] - E[X]^2
var *= float(N)/float(N-1)
```

In many cases (and many examples) it is omitted because N is very large, which makes correction pretty much invisible - f.e., if you have statistical error 1% but N is in millions, correction is of no practical use.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect! I think my error was that I didn’t use the 2nd and 3rd s.d. (And that I tried to calculate them by hand) x

Comment: @pinkbonsai You're welcome. If this answered your question, please accept the answer. Please check the update as well for minor detail

Comment: I’d be happy to. How do I do that? I think I’ve already clicked the up arrow. (Sorry, I’m still quite new to the forum )

Comment: @pinkbonsai below up-down arrows there is a grey check sign. You click it and it will become green - accepted as answering the question. I personally follow simple policy - any answer which, I believe, contribute to the pool of knowledge, I click up arrow. Answer which best answers my question I accept by clicking on check sign.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ve clicked it now. I think that’s a great policy. Will definitely be doing that from now on :)

Comment: @pinkbonsai Good luck!